# Is it possible to have ampersand's in XML HTTP Tags?

Tags: xml

I was wondering are there any issues with having ampersands in XML tags? Or does this cause issues when producing and consuming the XML document?

Comment: Only the characters "<" and "&" are strictly illegal in XML.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

Comment: I suggest you lookup http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn) forbids them.

An element name is defined as:

> Name     ::=      NameStartChar (NameChar)*

So, a `NameStartChar` followed by any number of `NameChar`.

Where:

> NameStartChar    ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
>   [4a]

And:

> NameChar      ::=      NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "XML HTTP Tags". But ampersands must be escaped as `&amp;` wherever they occur in XML.

Comment: sorry i meant if someone created a xml doc like.....

    <http>www.exmaple.com/example?test=id&person=test<\http> ......Would the & be a valid charactor.

Comment: No it wouldn't. As I said, & must be escaped as `&amp;`